# How can we reset apache2

Tags: apache2

By mistake I have applied the command,

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

after that i can't run apache2

How can I solve this?

Comment: How on earth do you "accidentally" run that command?

Comment: restore /etc/init.d/apache2 from your backups.

Comment: Just download the source and copy the init script over, look at http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi the newer version have `httd.init` and `htcacheclean.init` in `build/rpm/`, the older ones should have something similar. You can also try mine if you wish http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=dCfMtwXf

Comment: I have copied the file from another system, but not works

Answer (score 25):

Reinstall and start Apache with the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo service apache2 start
```

`apt purge` uninstalls the specified app (in this case, apache)

`apt install` installs the specified app (in this case, apache)

`service start` starts the specified app (in this case, apache)

Comment: can you please provide more explanation?

Comment: `apt` `purge` will remove and uninstall apache2.  
`install` will do as the name implies.   
Then The last line starts Apahe2

Answer (score 0):

If Apache2 is installed as part of a system package (e.g. with Debian apt-get), then you should be able to get it back by removing and reinstalling the package (I hesitate to say use e.g. the reinstall option because I don't think that touches config files). You could also fetch the source package and find the init.d file in that and copy it back.